# Handle with AlertDialog into the AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handler, android-alertdialog

I am trying to call `AlertDialog` into `AsyncTask`. I wrote this code and it works, but when I choose item in the `AlertDialog` `AlertDialog` freezes but foreground UI is working. Help me please to write right code for my task or help me please to fix freeze `AlertDialog` after choosing item. I was trying to call `dismiss()` method before `uiHandler.getLooper.suit()` line, but nothing was changed.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    Looper.prepare();
    final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();
    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder chooser = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
            facultyChooser.setTitle("Choose")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setItems(faculties, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            uiHandler.getLooper().quit();
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }
    });
    Looper.loop();
}
```

PS: It's not full code for easier reading.

Comment: uiHandler.getLooper().quit(); is called in onClick. check by removing that..

Comment: @Aun, if I remove it Looper will not stop. and nothing after closing the dialog nothing happenes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error occurred because you try to run `Handler` (UI thread) in `doInBackground` (background thread). My solution will make sure your alert dialog created in the UI thread.

Move this code :

```
       AlertDialog.Builder chooser = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        facultyChooser.setTitle("Choose")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setItems(faculties, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        uiHandler.getLooper().quit();
                    }
                })
                .create()
                .show();
```

To the `onPostExecute` or `onPreExecute` to make sure the dialog is created on the UI thread.

And delete  `final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();` because `onPostExecute`/`onPreExecute` is already running on UI thread.

Comment: I cannot move it into the onPostExecute because onPostExecute is saving my parsing results.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you dont need Looper and all in this case. Can you please try following?

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
     Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder chooser = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
            facultyChooser.setTitle("Choose")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setItems(faculties, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's working. Thank U for answer. Where can I read about Handler and Android threads to understant it like U )))?

Comment: Lol... early happy ((( Afrer }); parsing begining and handler dont wait for AlertDialog choose and begins parsing immediately. How can I make like `join()` until dialog item is not choosen?